# Replace JSON null value with empty String?

Tags: json, rest, grails, grails-3.0

When working with JSON response data is there a way to replace 'null' values in the returned JSON to empty Strings "" ?

```
{
    "description": null,
    "identifier": "84471a9f-bb4b-46aa-b55b-c3b13a5106c0",
}
```

Should actually be

```
{
    "description": "",
    "identifier": "84471a9f-bb4b-46aa-b55b-c3b13a5106c0",
}
```

I am using the latest stable release of Grails 3 (3.0.9)

Comment: ... but `null` and `""` aren't the same. They are actually different. You might want to explain why you are trying to do this. Perhaps you are trying to treat a symptom instead of curing the illness.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore i agree that they are different. But when rendering a domain object with properties and a property is null i would expect that null is replaced with "". In the context of our application this would make sense. But i also see what you are mentioning. Having the explicit null is maybe not that bad.

Comment: You are right, having `null` isn't bad. In fact, it's correct. Having `""` in place of `null` when the value is actually `null` would be bad.